# Print Large SVG in multiple pages (A4)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, gantt-chart

Good morning,
cere's my problem: I'm using Twoproject Gantt in my company website ([link to gantt](https://gantt.twproject.com/applications/gantt/distrib/gantt.jsp)). I want it to be printable.

Problem: the gantt is a very long  and it gets printed only partially in a single A4 page. I would like it to be printable entirely, and even better if it extends in multiple A4 pages.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution: I used the technique written here to split the table across multiple pages [link](http://salman-w.blogspot.it/2013/04/printing-wide-html-tables.html). Then foreach piece of table I cloned the svg and changed the visibile part accordingly using viewBox attribute

Comment: Mind sharing your solution? I need to split a SVG image up to print on multiple pages.

Answer (score 1):

For HTML file containing SVG elements, I use `Opera` browser and `Adobe Acrobat Reader` application as explained on `Superuser` site.

[https://superuser.com/questions/161313/print-a-huge-svg](https://superuser.com/questions/161313/print-a-huge-svg/1542154#1542154)